# i2c userspace access blocked when kernel driver running

Tags: c++, linux

Working on porting code from QNX to Linux and ran into what appears to be a race condition between a user-space I2C driver and the kernel based PMIC I2C driver.  Once the sysinit begins to launch it attempts to access the I2C bus, which the initial accesses work, but then about a 1.5 second window occurs where the code gets Resource Manager errors "Bad File Descriptor".

If run the code as a separate binary after the sysinit and kernel initialization is complete it all works perfectly.  Unfortunately cannot disconnect the kernel PMIC driver easily since it's configuring the GPPs voltages and need that to happen in the kernel boot.

Any ideas on how to prevent the kernel driver from blocking the user space I2C driver?

Comment: place the user space code later in the `rcx.d`?

Comment: Ok, this has me really confused.  Delayed the start of the sysinit code by 10s (tried incrementally smaller cases which also didn't work so went for something big).  Still results in the same error.  Which tells me the kernel is long done with the PMIC initialization and the bus should be completely available for user space code...